# What are the advantages/disadvantages of using the karnaugh map instead of the truth table

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, karnaugh-map

What should I use? Or are there special occasion where I should use one over the other?

Comment: It's been years but I'll guess :) I think a Karnaugh map helps lead to minimal required logic for the problem. It's a special case of a truth table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The K map does not necessarily *fail* for higher dimensions. The problem is that it is so difficult to visualize for more than five variables. A 4 variable K-map is 2 dimensional and easy to visualize. A 5 variable is three dimensional, but is still manageable from a visualization standpoint, because the 2 states of the 5th variable only require visually moving from one plane to the next, without moving in the x or y directions of either plane. Just getting equations correct with more than 5 variables is difficult enough using the K map, much less considering an optimum set of terms ("core" prime implicants and "choice" prime implicants).

Answer (score 0):

A truth table is a list of every possible output for every possible input. As you can imagine, these can get quite large. From the truth table, you can directly get a boolean expression via sum of products, but this is also a rather large expression. Karnaugh maps take truth tables and provide a visual way to produce a much simpler formula for expressing the same logic. That said, any time you produce a truth table, you can and probably should produce a K-Map to simplify the logic.

Answer (score 0):

A k map use reduces the number of logic gates to be used to solve an logic expression and hence reduces the error

Answer (score 0):

The disadvantage of k map :

- It is not suitable for computer reduction.
- It is not suitable when the number of variables involved  exceed four.
- Care must be taken to field in every cell with the relevant entry, such as a 0, 1 (or) don't care terms.